# How to create a member function which points (or refers) to another member function of the same class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

in a few words my problem is that I have two different methods of a single class, and I would like to have a third method of that class which could point to my first or my second method.
A simplified code would look like :

```
typedef void(*func)(void);  // The type isn't good I believe

class Foo
{
  private:
  void f1(void){return;}
  void f2(void){return;}


  public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  void& f(void); // what should be the returned type here ? func& ? void& ? 

  void associate_f(int a)
  {
    if (a==1)
      f = f1; // or anything like that
    else
      f = f2;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo * foo = new Foo();
  foo->associate_f(1);
  return 0;
}
```

If there are other ways to do the same trick, I'd like to know them !

Comment: Wouldn't virtual inheritance be more appropriate to solve that?

Comment: You could search for method pointer. Your type func is a pointer to function, not a pointer to method (that needs the implied 'this' pointer).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to use virtual polymorphism with the [*Template Method Pattern*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1) for such case:

```
class FooBase
{
  protected:
  virtual void inner() = 0;

  public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  void f(void) {
      inner();
  } 
};

class Foo1 : public FooBase {
    void inner() {}
}

class Foo2 : public FooBase {
    void inner() {}
}

int main()
{
  Foo * foo1 = new Foo1();
  foo1->f();
  Foo * foo2 = new Foo2();
  foo2->f();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this is a better solution in general, OP might want to change the behavior by calling `associate_f` several times on the same instance.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That sounds like a flawed design. Id prefer to attach some strategy class in such case (if state of the original instance needs to be kept).

Comment: Thanks, but @FrançoisAndrieux 's solution is more appropriate to  my actual code, which I had to simplify to create this thread !

Comment: @valadeaurélien Well, there might be more than one approach for the problem as you describe it. Depends on your _real use case_ what should be preferred. The straightforward solution was given in _@DrPizza_'s answer.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, and to be honest, I don't believe this kind of trick about functionnals is the best solution in my case, but I ask by curiosity. Then I would understand if you say that was a stupid question without further explanations of what I was actually trying to do !

Comment: @valadeaurélien You probably oversimplified your example.

Comment: Sorry, first post. Let's say I gave myself some room of progression !

Comment: @valadeaurélien No problem. That's why I was answering. In principle your question is OK.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to store a pointer to a member function, so you need to use [pointers to member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions).

```
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef void(Foo::*func_ptr)(void);

private:
    void f1(void) { return; }
    void f2(void) { return; }

    func_ptr f_ptr;

public:
    void f(void) {
        (this->*f_ptr)();
    }

    void associate_f(int a)
    {
        if (a == 1)
            f_ptr = &f1;
        else
            f_ptr = &f2;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.associate_f(1);
    foo.f();    // Calls f1()
    return 0;
}
```

The previous example will let `f()` call the associated function. If you are trying to return a pointer to it instead, the simplest way would be to use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to bundle `this` with the member function.

Example :

```
#include <functional>

class Foo
{
private:
    void f1(void) { return; }
    void f2(void) { return; }


public:
    std::function<void()> f(void) {
        return f_ptr;
    }

    void associate_f(int a)
    {
        if (a == 1)
            f_ptr = [this]() {f1();};
        else
            f_ptr = [this]() {f2();};
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> f_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.associate_f(1);
    foo.f();    // Returns a "reference" to f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1):

Gonna straight up ignore the OP until he justifies his question. Like, maybe he has some reason for wanting to mess around with function pointers and so on, but he hasn't described one.

```
struct Foo {
    void f() {
        switch(selector) {
        case 1: f1(); break;
        default: f2(); break;
        }
    }

    void associate_f(int selector_) {
        selector = selector_;
    }

private:
    void f1() {}
    void f2() {}

    int selector;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and the reason was just curiosity in my case ! ;)

Comment: @valadeaurélien: well there may be better answers than mine, but it would really depend on the specifics of what you're trying to do. If you have no particular goal in mind, my answers is as good as any.

Comment: Absolutely. However, if we suppose I have to call my function f a many times, would it be faster to make her point to another function instead of switching between several possibilities at every call ?

Comment: That's where things get harder to predict. I expect that my solution is faster than the `std::function` approach, but it's harder to predict when compared to a virtual function. Both the virtual call and the branch are going to be predicted by the processor, and I don't know which would come out ahead in general. The pointer to member function should probably be the same or a bit worse than the virtual call.

Comment: And regarding @R Sahu 's solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that using the `typedef` below won't work.

```
typedef void(*func)(void);
```

It defines `func` to be a type of function that takes nothing and returns `void`. What you need is a type for a member function pointer.

```
class Foo
{
   private:

      using function_ptr = void (Foo::*)(void);

      function_ptr f;

   ...

};
```

Here's your posted code updated to use a member function pointer.

```
class Foo
{
   private:

      using function_ptr = void (Foo::*)(void);

      void f1(void){return;}
      void f2(void){return;}

   public:

      Foo() {}
      ~Foo() {}
      function_ptr f;

      void associate_f(int a)
      {
         if (a==1)
            f = &Foo::f1;
         else
            f = &Foo::f2;
      }
};

int main()
{
  Foo * foo = new Foo();
  foo->associate_f(1);
  return 0;
}
```

You can get more details on pointers to member variables and member functions at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer.

Comment: Won't compile unfortunately : " ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say « &Foo::f1 » [-fpermissive] "

Comment: @valadeaurélien, use `&Foo::f1` and `&Foo::f2` then.